# Lubuntu 11.10 wifi flickering on & off

Tags: 11.10, wireless, lubuntu

the wifi on my computer was running fine after I installed lubuntu 11.10, skip ahead a month or two and I started to get problems with my wifi just turning off then back on with no notice when my computer was unplugged. a few weeks later, now this problem happens even when plugged in. sometimes it happens right after I turn on my computer, sometimes not right away. it is starting to get difficult to deal with...

If it helps, I never had this problem with ubuntu 11.10 (with the same computer)

My computer is a toshiba L505

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uumm you seem to imply you may have updated to 12.04 LTS but all your references are to 11.10.  Nonetheless, most things to look at for your problem are not related to the OS.

1) Have you added anything like a wireless home phone, fluorescent lights, or microwave lately?  If so, turn them off or unplug them to see if your problem disappears.

2) If your laptop has an on-off switch for its wireless, make sure the switch is well seated in the on position.

3) If you have moved your laptop, try moving it back or rotating it 90 degrees to see if that has an effect

4) Look for other wifi signals on the same channel as yours.  Perhaps a neighbor has set up an AP and you are fighting each other.  If you have an Android phone, try WiFi Analyzer to see what signals the are.  If not, try iwconfig to see which of your network interfaces is you wireless.  Assuming it is wlan0, try iwlist wlan0 scanning | less and look at the channels and strengths to see if anything looks like a conflict.

I hope those ideas help.